# Magento CMS-Page template not loading after POST request

Tags: php, magento

So i have a strange problem with Magento. I try to fix some existing code and i have a page for a newsletter registration where an external script is loaded from another company. This is a short newsletter script to add or remove that customers to the external newsletter system.

That script is added with the following code as block in the content field in a magento page (CMS).

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/newsletter.phtml"}}
```

When i go to the page i can see my form. When i submit my empty form i come to the same site and the form is loaded again with some messages that the form is not filled in correctly so thats ok until this point everything works fine.

When i fill the mandatory fields and submit them i get an empty content so the complete form isn't loading anymore. I have added some output to the start of that file (newsletter.phtml) and its not shown so the complete file isn't loading. I have checked all of my logs and there are no errors.

When i do the following:

```
123
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/newsletter.phtml"}}
```

in my page nothing is shown. Is is possible that there are some limitations in Magento or that the script overrides an important POST variable?

To answer the question from Elavarasan

```
<?php $newsletter_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/shop/newsletter/index.php"; ?>
<?php include "$newsletter_path"; ?>
```

in the newsletter.phtml is only the include to that external script. That was working fine. But now the complete content isn't loading only if i send the filled form.

Comment: Can you post that code of newsletter.phtml file ?

Comment: @Elavarasan i have edited my question with some more informations :)

Comment: It is not a good way to include php file like this (as per magento standardization ). Put your code in that phtml file only.

Comment: That is the existing code... the problem is that this is in a different location i can try it but i think thats not working well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found that problem. The script raised an exception very deep in that external code. That causes an Exception at that point. After that Exception the whole content wasn't loading and the complete content field was ignored and was empty.

That was a very tricky problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've only been able to use ajax when creating forms in CMS pages, you can assign a block in the controller and output whatever you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The questions is that was working why is it not working anymore? And whats the difference between and Ajax POST request and a normal post request? Why should that work?